# cv2.imwrite cannot work after I convert my .py file into .exe file. Is anyone can help me to solve this issue?

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller, executable

This is my code. It works well and able to write the image to the specified folder in IDE. But, after converting the .py file to .exe file by PyInstaller, cv2.imwrite does not work anymore. Is there anyone can help me to solve this issue?
# enter code here
import cv2
import os

```
# Image path
image_path = r'C:\Users\Meadow\Desktop\Saving Images\jeremy.jpg'

# Image directory
directory = r'C:\Users\Meadow\Desktop\Saving Images'

# Using cv2.imread() method to read the image
img = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Change the current directory to specified directory 
os.chdir(directory)

# List files and directories in 'C:/Users/Rajnish/Desktop/GeeksforGeeks'  
print("Before saving image:")  
print(os.listdir(directory))

# Filename
filename = 'savedImage.jpg'

# Using cv2.imwrite() method
# Saving the image
cv2.imwrite(filename, img)

# List files and directories  
# in 'C:/Users / Rajnish / Desktop / GeeksforGeeks'  
print("After saving image:")  
print(os.listdir(directory))

print('Successfully saved')
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work. Please share the error.

Comment: If there is no error, check for the file in the directory you are running the executable from.

Comment: Create an error.log file and wrap the code in a `try` `except` block. Write the error inside the error.log and tell us what the results are.

Comment: thank you for commenting. After i run the .exe file, none image is saved into the directory I specified.

Comment: By when I run it as a .py file, it works and image is saved in the directory i specified. Just that after i convert the .py file into .exe file, cv2.imwrite seems does not work anymore.

Comment: I convert the .py file into .exe file by using Pyinstaller.

pyinstaller --onefile -w savingImage.py